# Can I use capital module name for rails4 routes like 'EC'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to use a controller with `EC` module like `EC::HomeController`.

```
# app/cotrollers/ec/home_controller.rb

class EC::HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

It works in rails console.

```
[1] pry(main)> EC::HomeController
=> EC::HomeController
```

---

But in `routes.rb` it doesn't work...

```
# config/routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :ec do
    namespace :home do
      get "/" => :index
    end
  end
end
```

And access to `http://localhost:3000/ec/home`, then get

```
LoadError in Ec::HomeController#index
Unable to autoload constant Ec::HomeController, expected 
/Users/wadako/coincheck/app/controllers/ec/home_controller.rb to define it
```

It loads `Ec::HomeController` not `EC::HomeController`.

Can't I use capital module name for rails4 routes?

Comment: Did you try `rake routes` to see what your current setup yields? Also did you try `:EC` in the routes?

Comment: Something to consider is Rails defaults to [`camel_case`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) for module names etc

Answer (score 3):

in `config/initializers` create `inflections.rb`. In this file define:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'EC'
end
```

This will allow you to use your module name in caps.

Comment: Nice! Should be marked as answer, is definitely the correct way to handle it

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL thx! Glad it finally (2 years after I've posted it) happened to be useful :)

Answer (score 1):

Lets work on that `routes.rb`!

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :home, only: :index, module: 'EC'  
end
```

This should give you a route helper `home_path` that maps to `EC:HomeController#index`